# How to create a keras model that depends dynamically on the input dimension (not batch size)?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

If you use the keras subclass api and you want to spawn a bunch of layers (n) depending on the the input dimension x = (batch_dim, n) is there a way to do this inside the build method?

Or is the only way to pass the input dim into the model at **init** time so the layers can be created within the init scope?

UPDATE: pseudo-code (untested) example

```
class BigModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
        self._my_submodels = list()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        for i in range(input_shape[1]):
            self.my_submodels.append(MyModel(param=i))

    def call(self, *inputs):
        stuff = list()
        for submodel in self.my_submodels:
            stuff.append(submodel(*inputs))
        # do something amazing with all the models
        fan_in = ... # combine 
        return fan_in
```

You could *probably* rewrite the whole structure in a more vectorized way using one model with a lot of splits but it will be harder to read and deal with and I think the new tf 2.0 allows this kind of dynamism without any cost penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of using `batch_shape = (batch_size, input_dim)`, use `batch_shape=(None, input_dim)` which allows arbitrary number of batch_size.

Comment: I mean if I want create *input_dim* models of different sizes. So if the input data has dimension 10, I will create 10 models that are totally independent. This likely has to happen in the "build" method I think.

Comment: what do you mean by "if the input data has dimension 10, I will create 10 models that are totally independent". Could you please provide an example?

Comment: wrote a quick sketch